# Get png with transparency from iPhone using File API

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, fileapi

Im using a input (type="file") with fileAPI (fileReader / dataURL) to get png (with transparency) images and then show up into a website. This work great in desktops. I just click the button, browse an select my image an then it will show up on the site.

In iOS iPhone (not tested on other ios devices) when you click the button, the browser show up options for take a photo or choose a image from camera roll. I choose my image on cam roll an it show up with a white background; but this is a png 24 with transparency, and that background should not be there (like in the desktop).

I found that its probably a problem with camera roll removing the transparency of the image. So Im wondering if someone has ever got a png with transparency from the iphone using the html 5 file api, and if so, how to do it?

Note: I tried using dropbox (an others apps that alow to copy images to cam roll) hoping that the png images dont loose their transparency but somehow all the images ended with the annoying background when are imported in the site.

This is the code im currently using for get the images via File API:

```
function init() {
    var bHaveFileAPI = (window.File && window.FileReader);
    document.getElementById("inputid").addEventListener("change", onFileChanged);
}
function onFileChanged(theEvt) {
    var thefile = theEvt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var resultdata = evt.target.result;
        $('<img>')
            .attr('title', thefile.name)
            .attr('src', evt.target.result)
            .prependTo('#imgin');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(thefile);
}
window.addEventListener("load", init);
```